# ExtJS 5 Dynamically chage a Hyberlink

Tags: extjs

I'm having some issue of using ExtJS-5 to set some Hyberlink which also could be dynamically changed(according to a REST GET call).

Now I'm able to set a label as a Hyberlink using it's 'html' config which makes it clickable and jump to another page. Also according to the DOC file, if I assign the 'text' config to a 'Label' it will disable the 'html' property and only display the 'text'. So now I can change the 'text' of label Dynamically but they are not clickable.

Questions:

1. Should I use 'Label' for what I'm trying to do or use something else?
2. DOC shows 'Label' has no getText or getHTML method, then how to read its 'value'? like I want to pass it to the BackEnd. (getValue() doesn't work)

Comment: Just found a way to solve it. Simply use a method called update and put the html code in there when a listener is triggered. so the label would be changed and also clickable. Still trying to find a way to get the 'html' value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Label is perfectly fine for doing this
2. ExtJS doesn't provide any method of getting text value, cause we can read it directly